# ArcGIS Collector - Change polygon symbology to black if it has been edited

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, domains, arcgis-collector, arcade

I have a web map for ArcGIS Collector. The symbology is based on farm type in 2021, "FARM_2021". The symbology is very intuitive, vineyards are purple, strawberries are red, cotton is white, etc. I have a coded-value domain field for farm type in 2022, "FARM_2022". Operator clicks Edit -> clicks the "FARM_2022" field, and a dropdown menu shows the domain values he can select for this year.

How would I keep my 2021 farm type symbology, but when a value for "FARM_2022" is entered, the polygon turns black? The black polygons would let the operator know which farms have been surveyed already.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do that in Collector, well I couldn't a couple of years ago when I did a river survey. I needed to be able to mask sites that had been visited and I came up with this idea which worked really well. You have a separate layer that is symbolised by 1 field, a text field holding a Y or N. N was symbolised as a tiny dot whilst a Y was a big black square, as shown below.

[image: Mask layer]

When I had completed the survey which was captured in another layer, I then edit the mask layer and set the field to Y for the feature so its symbology updated to the black square.

This does mean you need to edit both layers, which was trivial but it does require that each existing survey site had a corresponding existing mask point to update.

Comment: I had to do something very similar to this last year. My go-around was adding a second web layer with all of the farms. All farms had no color. When the operator entered the "FARM_2021" value, he would go to the next field "Status", and change it from Null to "Surveyed". The symbology of this editable layer was black when "Status" = "Surveyed". This blank/black layer was on top of the color-coded farm uneditable layer.  The problem with this method is that Collector is notorious for slow load-up times and syncing issues, especially in rural farm areas.